# Generalisations of the Gronwall's lemma

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Suppose we have the following differential inequality

$F''(w)\le \frac{p-1}{p}\frac{(F'(w))^2}{F(w)}$ on $w\in(w_0,w_0+\varepsilon)$, $w_0>0$, $\varepsilon>0$, $p>1$. In addition, $F(w)>0$, $F'(w)>0$ for $w\in[w_0,w_0+\varepsilon)$.

Let's consider the solution of the Cauchy problem

$\begin{cases}G''(w)= \frac{p-1}{p}\frac{(G'(w))^2}{G(w)},& w\in(w_0,w_0+\varepsilon),\\G'(w_0)=F'(w_0),&\\G(w_0)=F(w_0),&\end{cases},$ which can be written explicitly:

$G(w) = F(w_0)\left(1+\frac{F'(w_0)}{F(w_0)}\frac{w-w_0}{p}\right)^p$.

Is it possible to compare the functions $F$ and $G$ in any meaningful way? This case fits neither the canonical version of the [Gronwall's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_lemma) nor its [generalisation by Bihari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%27s_inequality), because it involves second derivatives.

I'd be glad to hear all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the seconde derivative of $F^{1/p}$. you'll find that it is negative, and the seconde derivative of $G^{1/p}$ is 0, so we have $(F^{1/p})^{''}\leq (G^{1/p})^{''} $
Then by integrating twice you'll have $F^{1/p}\leq G^{1/p} $ and then $F\leq G$

Comment: Thank you! In fact, this problem itself came from hypothesis of concavity of the function $F^{1/p}$.